# How to get a list of available input- and output-filters for telegraf

Tags: telegraf, telegraf-inputs-plugin, telegraf-output-plugins

Is there any way to get a list which input- and output-filters are currently supported by a given installation?

Comment: Are you talking about `--input-list` and `--output-list` flags? Colon-separated values from those lists are used in `input-filter` and `output-filter` to enable a subset of all available plugins in telegraf.